# Python List - splitting on an empty object in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to split my Python List using ("") Empty Object in the list.

```
['', u'WO0000008971346', u'', u'Low', u'Assigned', u'', u'',
'', u'WO0000008971321', u'', u'Low', u'Assigned', u'', u'',
'', u'WO0000008971307', u'', u'Low', u'Assigned', u'', u'',
'', u'WO0000008971247', u'', u'Low', u'Pending', u'Client Action Required',     
u'17/04/2018 15:08:49','', u'WO0000008971245',u'', u'Low', u'Pending', u'Client Action Required', 
u'17/04/2018 15:07:10','', u'WO0000008971235', u'',
u'Low', u'In Progress', u'', u'17/04/2018 15:03:50']
```

Any conventions to split this using python?

Comment: What are you trying to do, what is the desired outcome? what have you tried?

Comment: Do you just want every other element in the list? Do you want to remove the `''`? Maybe `[x for x in myList if x]` is what you need?

Comment: or `list(filter(None, myList))` might help

Comment: do you mean group items in several sub-lists?

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The better question may be how did you end up with such a list and try to fix it upstream.

Comment: I got it from Crawling a table using selenium. after i collected the table, the list came out to be like this.

Answer (score 4):

you probably mean "create sublists from list, separated by the empty strings".

In that case, use `itertools.groupby`, the condition is "string is empty":

```
import itertools

s = ['', u'WO0000008971346', u'', u'Low', u'Assigned', u'', u'',
'', u'WO0000008971321', u'', u'Low', u'Assigned', u'', u'',
'', u'WO0000008971307', u'', u'Low', u'Assigned', u'', u'',
'', u'WO0000008971247', u'', u'Low', u'Pending', u'Client Action Required', u'17/04/2018 15:08:49',
'', u'WO0000008971245',u'', u'Low', u'Pending', u'Client Action Required', u'17/04/2018 15:07:10',
'', u'WO0000008971235', u'', u'Low', u'In Progress', u'', u'17/04/2018 15:03:50']

result = [list(x) for k,x in itertools.groupby(s,key=bool) if k]

print(result)
```

`bool` is the key function which yields `True` if the string isn't empty. We then filter on a `True` condition to keep the non-empty groups.

result:

```
[['WO0000008971346'], ['Low', 'Assigned'], ['WO0000008971321'], ['Low', 'Assigned'],
['WO0000008971307'], ['Low', 'Assigned'], ['WO0000008971247'], 
['Low', 'Pending', 'Client Action Required', '17/04/2018 15:08:49'], 
['WO0000008971245'], ['Low', 'Pending', 'Client Action Required', '17/04/2018 15:07:10'],
['WO0000008971235'], ['Low', 'In Progress'], ['17/04/2018 15:03:50']]
```

If you wanted to remove the multiple occurrences of the empty strings instead (to keep a flat list, delimited by empty string, it's the same idea, but with a flatten, and a conditional:

```
result2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x if k else [''] for k,x in itertools.groupby(s,key=bool)))
```

yields:

```
['', 'WO0000008971346', '', 'Low', 'Assigned', '', 'WO0000008971321', '',
 'Low', 'Assigned', '', 'WO0000008971307', '', 'Low', 'Assigned', '', 
'WO0000008971247', '', 'Low', 'Pending', 'Client Action Required', 
'17/04/2018 15:08:49', '', 'WO0000008971245', '', 'Low', 'Pending', 'Client Action Required',
'17/04/2018 15:07:10', '', 'WO0000008971235', '', 'Low', 'In Progress', '', '17/04/2018 15:03:50']
```

Comment: Perhaps `' ', ' '` in the original list should spawn a `[]` in the result.

Comment: @JohnColeman it's not very useful since it's redundant: the sub-lists are there because there were spaces (except, maybe at start & end). You may want to keep the exact number of blanks, though, and for this you just have to remove `if k` test.

Comment: OP would need to clarify. In string `.split()` two delimiters in a row spawns an empty string in the split list. It isn't clear what OP intends by two empty strings in a row. (+1) for a good answer for one interpretation of the question.

Comment: @JohnColeman "OP would need to clarify" is an understatement :) thanks, I think there's no other way to interpret OP question, and the fine tuning you're noting can be added without changing the bulk of the answer.

Comment: I needed [['WO0000008971346'], ['Low', 'Assigned']] in a single list. :)

Comment: Ya , i tired grouping it like this but As there is WO0000008971245',u'', u'Low', u'Pending', u'Client Action Required', u'17/04/2018 15:07:10' , extra elements in the list , i need the sublist to delimit on the empty element. which occurs after every sublist.

Comment: it's better grouped as lists but with the same idea, we can do the flat list with empty lists as separators (it's just like removing the duplicate items)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , the list that i have has 8 elements , which includes all the 'code'" "'code' elements too. so i'm thinking its simpler to just convert the list into sublist with 8 elements in it? how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need sublist of 3 elements after deleting the empty elements.

**Demo**

```
data = ['', u'WO0000008971346', u'', u'Low', u'Assigned', u'', u'', 
'', u'WO0000008971321', u'', u'Low', u'Assigned', u'', u'', 
'', u'WO0000008971307', u'', u'Low', u'Assigned', u'', u'', 
'', u'WO0000008971247', u'', u'Low', u'Pending', u'Client Action Required', u'17/04/2018 15:08:49', 
'', u'WO0000008971245',u'', u'Low', u'Pending', u'Client Action Required', u'17/04/2018 15:07:10', 
'', u'WO0000008971235', u'', u'Low', u'In Progress', u'', u'17/04/2018 15:03:50']

data = filter(None, data)
print([data[x:x+3] for x in xrange(0, len(data), 3)])
```

**Output:**

```
[[u'WO0000008971346', u'Low', u'Assigned'], [u'WO0000008971321', u'Low', u'Assigned'], [u'WO0000008971307', u'Low', u'Assigned'], [u'WO0000008971247', u'Low', u'Pending'], [u'Client Action Required', u'17/04/2018 15:08:49', u'WO0000008971245'], [u'Low', u'Pending', u'Client Action Required'], [u'17/04/2018 15:07:10', u'WO0000008971235', u'Low'], [u'In Progress', u'17/04/2018 15:03:50']]
```

Comment: Ya , this works :)! Thanks Rakesh!

Comment: Ya , i tired grouping it like this but As there is WO0000008971245',u'', u'Low', u'Pending', u'Client Action Required', u'17/04/2018 15:07:10' , extra elements in the list , i need the sublist to delimit on the empty element. which occurs after every sublist.